# Power Apps integer comparison error (contains)

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I'm taking the number of the contact record and I want to compare text. This returns false even if the number is 555555555.

I tried converting it to text but it still returns false

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the flow I tested with.

[image: Flow]

The left hand side expression is ... `string(variables('Number'))` ... and the right hand side expression is ... `string(55555)` ... that produced a `true` result.

Using double quotes around the `55555` also produced a result of `true`.

[image: Double Quotes]

You need to be careful with double quotes though, they disappear after your add and run the flow but the JSON definition will tell you the detailed story ...

**Number Comparison**

[image: Number Comparison]

**String Comparison**

[image: String Comparison]